# Iterate with asynchronous functions

Tags: asynchronous, java-8, vert.x

Using the [Twitch API](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference) and `vert.x` - I'm looking to continuously send requests to Twitch's API using a `WebClient` and Twitch's `cursor` response to go page by page. However I'm not sure how to go back and keep doing queries until a condition is met due to vert.x's asynchronous nature.

Here's my code so far

```
public void getEntireStreamList(Handler<AsyncResult<JsonObject>> handler) {
    JsonObject data = new JsonObject();

    getLiveChannels(100, result -> {
        if(result.succeeded()) {
            JsonObject json = result.result();
            String cursor = json.getJsonObject("pagination").getString("cursor");
            data.put("data", json.getJsonArray("data"));

            if(json.getJsonArray("data").size() < 100) { // IF NOT LAST PAGE
                // GO BACK AND DO AGAIN WITH CURSOR IN REQUEST
            }

            handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(data));
        } else
            handler.handle(Future.failedFuture(result.cause()));
    });
}
```

Ideally I'd be able to call `getLiveChannels` with the `cursor` String from the previous request to continue the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use Future composition.

Here's my code for your problem:

```
public void getEntireStreamList(Handler<AsyncResult<JsonObject>> handler) {
    JsonArray data = new JsonArray();
    // create initial Future for first function call
    Future<JsonObject> initFuture = Future.future();

    // complete Future when getLiveChannels completes
    // fail on exception
    getLiveChannels(100, initFuture.completer());

    // Create a callback that returns a Future
    // for composition.
    final AtomicReference<Function<JsonObject, Future<JsonObject>>> callback = new AtomicReference<>();
    // Create Function that calls composition with itself.
    // This is similar to recursion.
    Function<JsonObject, Future<JsonObject>> cb = new Function<JsonObject, Future<JsonObject>>() {
        @Override
        public Future<JsonObject> apply(JsonObject json) {
            // new Future to return
            Future<JsonObject> f = Future.future();
            // Do what you wanna do with the data
            String cursor = json.getJsonObject("pagination").getString("cursor");
            data.addAll(json.getJsonArray("data"));
            // IF NOT LAST PAGE
            if(json.getJsonArray("data").size() == 100) {
                // get more live channels with cursor
                getLiveChannels(100, cursor, f.completer());
                // return composed Future
                return f.compose(this);
            }
            // Otherwise return completed Future with results.
            f.complete(new JsonObject().put("data", data));
            return f;
        }
    };

    Future<JsonObject> composite = initFuture.compose(cb);
    // Set handler on composite Future (ALL composed futures together)
    composite.setHandler(result -> handler.handle(result));
}
```

The code + comments should speak for themselves if you read the Vert.x docs on [sequential Future composition](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_sequential_composition).